# How to select an instance of object from ComboBox that filled by objects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

The question may be dumb but I am a newbie in WPF, so I am sorry.
I found a lot of similar questions here, but none of them helped.

I have a form that gets some object with a `Location` property as input.
I want this `Location` property to be selected in the `ComboBox` when the form is shown.
I also want to make this property changeable during the lifecycle of the form.

I madea binding in this way:

```
<ComboBox Name="CB_Location" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation}" DisplayMemberPath="LocationName" SelectedValuePath="LocationID" SelectionChanged="CB_Location_SelectionChanged"/>
```

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

```
public Form(object _obj)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lctrl = new LocationController();
    Locations = lctrl.GetAllLocations();

    SelectedLocation = lctrl.GetLocationById(_obj.LocationID);

    DataContext = this;    
}

public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
public Location SelectedLocation; { get; set; }
```

The `ComboBox` is populated with objects correctly, but I cannot set the `SelectedItem` property correctly.

Comment: Why do you set SelectedValuePath without using SelectedValue? What is SelectedLocation? In case it is a property of type Location in the current DataContext, make sure its value is a Location object that is a member of the Locations collection. Otherwise turn it into a property of type `int`, bind SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem, and set it like `SelectedLocation = _obj.LocationID;`

Comment: Yes, SelectedLocation is property of Location type. An Locations collection contains all possbile Location including SelectedLocation.

Comment: `public Location SelectedLocation;` is a field, not a property.

Comment: @Clemens fixed this. Thank you. But still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue why the selected item is not set is because `SelectedLocation` is a field, which you cannot bind. For more information about binding sources, you can refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0).

> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object. The binding engine uses CLR reflection to get the values of the properties. Alternatively, objects that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or have a registered TypeDescriptionProvider also work with the binding engine.

In order to make your current code work, just make `SelectedLocation` a public property.

```
public Location SelectedLocation { get; set; }
```

Apart from that, if you only want to bind the selected item, setting a `SelectedValuePath` is useless.

```
<ComboBox Name="CB_Location"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation}"
          DisplayMemberPath="LocationName"
          SelectionChanged="CB_Location_SelectionChanged"/>
```

If you wanted to bind the `SelectedValue` where the `SelectedValuePath` is applicable instead, you would have to expose a property that matches the type of the selected value path, here `int`.

```
public int SelectedLocationID { get; set; }
```

Then you can bind this the `SelectedValue` with value path `LocationID` (without `SelectedItem`).

```
<ComboBox Name="CB_Location"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"
          DisplayMemberPath="LocationName"
          SelectedValuePath="LocationID"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedLocationID}"
          SelectionChanged="CB_Location_SelectionChanged"/>
```

---

Another note on updating properties. It seems that you do not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. If you set `Location` for instance, the user interface (here the `ComboBox`) will not reflect the change, as it does not get notified. Therefore, if you intend to change the `Location` or other properties bound in your form, you have to [implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), e.g.:

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private Location _selectedLocation;
   public Location SelectedLocation
   {
      get => _selectedLocation;
      set
      {
         if (_selectedLocation == value)
            return;
   
         _selectedLocation = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   // ...other code.
}
```

Comment: Thanks @thatguy. I already made SelectedLocation a public property. But SelectedLocation still is not correctly applied to combobox.

Comment: It's strange thing but it seems that SelectedLocationID did the trick. Now ComboBox displays Value and SelectionChanged is working. I'm just interesting now, which way is more correct: to stay it as is or to continue trying with something like ObservableCollection.

Comment: @PavelPolushin This should not be related to `ObservableCollection<T>`. You only need that if you modify your collection at runtime. If you create a collection in the constructor and never modify it, you do not need it, a simple list is enough (or read-only collection). Both approaches should work just fine, given that `GetLocationById` returns the _same_ instance of an item that is present in `Locations` as mm8 showed in the other answer. Both are _correct_, it depends on your use-case which fits better. It is just important that you **do not mix both approaches in XAML** (unexpected result).